# Large bitmasks of arbitrary length in c++

Tags: c++, bitmask

I have a graph with n nodes and a `std::set` for each node that saves the other nodes it can reach. I then compute the union of the set of two different nodes which can be really time consuming.

Therefore, I want to use a bitmask for each node where I set the k-th bit when I can reach node k and just use a bitwise OR to compute the union of two nodes. This works perfectly fine when I only have up to 64 nodes but how do I get a bitmask of length 1'000'000 which can still use bitwise OR?

Comment: How about [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) (or one of the alternatives mentioned in the linked reference)?

Comment: Unless you know the size at compile time (which I'd guess you probably don't), you might prefer a [boost dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) over a `std::bitset`. It supports bitwise `or`, but of course that's linear on the size once the number of elements is larger than your CPU can compute at once.

Comment: At best that's a 976kb bitmask!

Comment: I cannot use std::bitset since I don't know the size of the bitmask until I run the code and read the graphfile. I will have a look at the dynamic_bitset though.

Comment: What do you need the bitmask for? Does it have to be a bitmask, or you just want some flags? You could use `vector<bool>` or similar and just OR the values yourself. `vector<bool>`'s unusual implementation is coincidental here. You could also try `vector<bitset<8>>` or some combination.

Comment: @NeilKirk I just need a way to quickly compute the union of two sets so bitmasks came into my mind. Also, what do you mean with that's a 976kb bitmask at best? Is this maximum size dynamic_bitset can handle or is it just slower for larger bitmasks?

Comment: No, it's not a maximum. Bitmasks are not usually so big, but dynamic_bitset should still work.

Comment: @FirePrism, do you know about [the union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)? It sounds like you're working on some kind of graph partitioning problem, and union-find is fantastic for that kind of thing.

Comment: @pdw my sets are not disjoint so I don't think I can use union-find.